# How to send POST request multipart/form-data field as array for unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, go, multipartform-data, go-gin

I'm trying to make unit testing for my Go application that handles form data in multipart/form-data content type using gin (PostForm and PostFormArray) like

`x, y := c.PostForm("x"), c.PostFormArray("y")`

I have no problem on making a form field which have non-array value (PostForm) with mime/multipart library which Go provides like this

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
w := multipart.NewWriter(buf)

x, _ := w.CreateFormField("x")
x.Write([]byte("This is x value"))

w.Close()
```

which PostForm handles perfectly, now I'm wondering if there is any way to send a multipart/form-data field with an array as its value like `[]string{"this is y 1", "this is y 2"}` for it to work with gin's PostFormArray. Is it possible and how do I do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "send a multipart/form-data field with an array as its value" this is not how multipart works. multipart  has no notion of "array". What exactly do you want to send?

Comment: Have you tried `y1, _ := w.CreateFormField("y")` then `y1.Write([]byte("this is y 1"))`, and `y2, _ := w.CreateFormField("y")` then `y2.Write([]byte("this is y 2"))`?

Comment: @Volker I want to send a form field which can work with gin's PostFormArray, which basically means a key with multiple values I guess

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks, that does the trick! Can't believe I missed this hahahaha, if you want you can post your answer and I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create multiple fields with the same name, e.g.

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
w := multipart.NewWriter(buf)

x, _ := w.CreateFormField("x")
x.Write([]byte("This is x value"))

y1, _ := w.CreateFormField("y")
y1.Write([]byte("this is y 1"))

y2, _ := w.CreateFormField("y")
y2.Write([]byte("this is y 2"))

w.Close()
```

Comment: The simplest and to the point solution